# nrf24l01+ does not work with a battery, or very unreliably

Tags: power, battery, nrf24l01+

For a project in progress, I have an Arduino UNO sending a message when a condition occurs, and a Raspberry Pi that listens to it. Both are fitted with NRF24L01+ modules with antennas.

It works perfectly when the Arduino is powered from a wall socket, for instance using a 9V / 1A power supply. But when I try it with a [9V battery](http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/6LR61PL_EU.pdf) (which is supposed to supply 600 mAh), the Raspberry Pi receives only 1/10 of the messages.

Could you tell me:

1. Why this happens
2. How I can solve this problem (software / wiring / capacitor / ...)
3. What would be the best way to power an Arduino whose only job is to detect that a switch closes, and emit a message over the air

[Here](http://pastebin.com/S0BvhiMr) is the code of the emitter (Arduino). And [there](http://pastebin.com/PgcCYxNc) is the code of the receiver (Raspberry Pi).

Thank you.

Comment: 600mAh is capacity, not current.

Comment: 4 rechargeable AA batteries (4 x 1.2V)(bypassing the voltage regulator). Note that you will probably only get a few days of usage out of batteries, because you are using an UNO, since the USB-to-Serial chip doesn't sleep.

Comment: Actually I think I should be able to use just two AA batteries. I was just testing the design on the UNO. It's really not a low power device... The regulator sucks a lot of current, and there is the power LED. So it's probably using most of the juice of the 9V battery already, doing nothing.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [datasheet](http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/522.pdf) of another 9V battery, I should not expect more than 30 - 50 mA of constant current. This is probably the reason why.

Long story made short: One can not power a NRFL01+ reliably with a 9V battery.
I'd be better off using 2xAA batteries.

Comment: According to my measurements, the Uno would take 50 mA from a 9 V battery. You are already at the upper end of the range you quoted. Now power up a transmitter and the voltage probably drops so low it fails. `One can not power a NRFL01+ reliably with a 9V battery` - more like, "One can not power a Uno reliably with a 9V battery".

Comment: `I'd be better off using 2xAA batteries.` - why not 3xAA batteries? That's only 4.5 volts. Put it straight onto the 5 V pin.

Comment: Does anyone have idea/guess, for how long it will run on 3xAA batteries ?

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider is that a nrf24l01+ chip at full power will potentially be pulling more current than your 5v reg can supply, try a lower power setting on the PA.

Comment: This is exactly the opposite. NRF24L01+ draws maximum 14mA of current. Arduino Uno board draws much much more.

Answer (score 0):

Add a 100uf capacitor between ground and 3.3v directly on the nrf breakout. They're very susceptible to noise on the power supply. I had issues with the same thing and this solved it. Also, make sure you're powering from 3.3v. Also make sure you solder the negative to the negative!

[image: see capacitor placement]

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem while not exactly the same but it may include the solution. I have a arduino nano with the nrf24l01 with the adapter and antenna (PA LNA). Transmitter work well but the receiver only work/receive data when plug by USB to the computer, not using an external battery (by USB too). I search for hours looking for a solution (the capa, the robin nrf24 tutorial, SPI problem, power supply problem, trying with another nrf24 module...) without finding any reason for this unexpected behaviour. Then i figured out that  the USB cable that i use make a big difference: two were preventing transmission, one allowing transmission (the 3 cables perfectly work to upload sketch): i was thinking to a ground plan problem due to different size of USB cable but then i check the voltage arriving on the adapter of the nrf24l01. It was 4.7V for the cables that doesn't work, 4.6 with the cable that work. Then i just bypass the arduino alimentation of the nrf24l01  by using a regulated power supply directly applied on vcc and gnd of the adapter. By manually adjusting the voltage i could trigger the transmission with 4.5 V and stops it at 4.7V. I don't know why it's work like this (defect of the 5V to 3.3V regulator of the adapter?) but that do the trick for me. I know that it looks like a very unlikely solution for you but if you are desperate after hours of research, take a minute to put a voltmeter just before the adapter to look for difference in  the voltage in the condition where it works versus where it doesn't work.